# Ошибка при получении данных из MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

При попытке авторизации выкидывает варнинг:
PHP Warning:  Cannot use a scalar value as an array

Из за этого как то не понятно обрабатывается скрипт - при любых входных данных выкидывает, мол, данные не верные, и вообще ацтань от меня противный, иди повесься.

При попытке прогнать полученные данные из базы что через fetch_assoc, что через fetch_array - результат не меняется.

Код:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['login']) && ($_SESSION['pass'])) {
    echo 'Вы уже авторизованы!';
} else {
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $login = strip_tags($login);
    $pass = strip_tags($pass);
    $login = htmlspecialchars($login);
    $pass = htmlspecialchars($pass);
//$login = mysql_escape_string($login);
//$pass = mysql_escape_string($pass);
    include 'connect.php';
    $qu = mysql_query("select * from users where `login` = '$login'");
//mysql_fetch_assoc($qu);
    if ($qu['pass'] = md5($pass)) {
        $_SESSION['login'] = $login;
        $_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $qu['id'];
        echo 'Авторизация успешна!';
    } else {
        echo 'Такого сочетания логина и пароля не существует!';
    }
}
?>
```

Как это дело исправить можно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Вы видимо плохо понимаете что возвращает функция [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php).
2. У вас дублируется код с обработкой данных логина и пароля. Вынесите это в отдельный метод.

---

```
//Выполняем запрос
$result = mysql_query($query);
// Проверяем результат
// Это показывает реальный запрос, посланный к MySQL, а также ошибку. Удобно при отладке.
if (!$result) {
    $message  = 'Неверный запрос: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Запрос целиком: ' . $query;
    die($message);
}

// Используем результат
// Попытка напечатать $result не выведет информацию, которая в нем хранится
// Необходимо использовать какую-либо mysql-функцию, работающую с результатом запроса
// См. также mysql_result(), mysql_fetch_array(), mysql_fetch_row() и т.п.
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['firstname'];
    echo $row['lastname'];
    echo $row['address'];
    echo $row['age'];
}
```

Comment: ну его нафиг, пойду я PDO курить

Comment: @Виталий RS - вот и правильно!